# drupal 7 how to add a variable to a node

Tags: variables, drupal-7

I would like to be able to add the following to a node

```
<a id="$variables2" name="$variables2"></a><a id="inline"href="#$variables2">Node title</a>
```

it is an example . $variables 1 and $variables 2 would be variables from fields added to a specific content type..

It is to integrate fancybox

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_load`
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_load/7